# Excel automatically add comment with cell edit history

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in the "sheet macros" (right click sheet - view code).  It used to work but now it's not adding comments in my specified range A5:AQ155.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

'If (Target.Row > 3 And Target.Row < 155) Then Cells(Target.Row, "AT") = Now()

Const sRng As String = "A5:AQ155" ' change as required
Dim sOld As String
Dim sNew As String
Dim sCmt As String
Dim iLen As Long
Dim bHasComment As Boolean


With Target(1)
If Intersect(.Cells, Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
sNew = .Text
sOld = .Text
.Value = sNew
Application.EnableEvents = True


sCmt = "Edit: " & Format$(Now, "dd Mmm YYYY hh:nn:ss") & " by " & Application.UserName & Chr(10) & "Previous Text :- " & sOld


If Target(1).Comment Is Nothing Then
.AddComment
Else
iLen = Len(.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
End If


With .Comment.Shape.TextFrame
.AutoSize = True
.Characters(Start:=iLen + 1).Insert IIf(iLen, vbLf, "") & sCmt
End With
End With
End Sub
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: its working for me. Did you step through line-by-line to see where it does not do what you expected. When I say it worked for me, I mean it added a comment as described in your code. It **did not however, add the old text into the comment**. You need to used the `Undo` Command to get that information, then set it back to what was entered.

Comment: How can I run a macro like this step-by-step when it's triggered on an event like cell editing?

Comment: place a break on the `Application.EnableEvents = False` line (F9 in the VBE), then edit a cell :)

Comment: Ok so it's not ever hitting the breakpoint.  Something is preventing the macro from being triggered at all.

Comment: @user2836976 - go to the immediate window and type `Application.EnableEvents = True` then run the code again. You will also need to find a good place to set this back in your code. The way this line is written `If Intersect(.Cells, Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` the Events will never be re-enabled when a user makes a change outside the tested range, so the code will never fire again. For example, add an `Else` to the `If` block and write `Application.EnableEvents = True` and `Exit Sub` inside the `Else` construct.

Comment: Just a note - You have one part of this anchored, but please do so with the `Range` part too!  `If Intersect(.Cells, Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` should be `If Intersect(.Cells, .Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`

Comment: @BruceWayne - Added `Me.range(sRng)` to answer.  Using `.range(sRng)` alone caused the script to not run.

Answer (score 3):

The code stopped firing because Event Firing was disabled and never turned back on. The way the code is written, as soon as someone makes a change to the worksheet outside the range `A5:AQ155`, the Events become disabled without being turned back on, which means subsequent event triggers will not be fired (ie. - the next time you edit a cell).

If you make these slight tweaks in the code it should work as intended going forward.

However, before you do this type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the immediate window and hit Enter to turn events back on so that the code begins to fire again.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Const sRng As String = "A5:AQ155" ' change as required
Dim sOld As String
Dim sNew As String
Dim sCmt As String
Dim iLen As Long

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target

        sNew = .Value2
        Application.Undo
        sOld = .Value2
        .Value2 = sNew

        Application.EnableEvents = True

        sCmt = "Edit: " & Format$(Now, "dd Mmm YYYY hh:nn:ss") & " by " & Application.UserName & Chr(10) & "Previous Text :- " & sOld


        If .Comment Is Nothing Then
            .AddComment
        Else
            iLen = Len(.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
        End If

        With .Comment.Shape.TextFrame
            .AutoSize = True
            .Characters(Start:=iLen + 1).Insert IIf(iLen, vbLf, "") & sCmt
        End With

    End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When I try using this code as is, whenever I edit a cell, it reverts back to the previous cell contents before adding a comment with the text I tried to enter.

Comment: @user2836976 - sorry, `.Value2 = sOld` should have been `.Value2 = sNew`. I fixed it. Try now.

Comment: Hi Scott. That's exactly what I'm looking for but I don't want it to add a comment if this is the first entry for the cell. I want to track changes from the second entry. How can I do that?

Comment: I also noticed that once I enter a value in a cell I can't do "Undo".

Comment: @Sameh - For first point, you can check if the value before the change was blank by checking `Len(sOld)` for instance. For second point, `Undo` will not work when code changes a cell. You could store the old value if you want and include a revert button that resets to the old value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that got me the desired behavior.  I changed the first IF statement according to @Scott Holtzman's comment.  The IF statement now resets     `Application.EnableEvents = True` before ending the macro with `End Sub`

EDIT: Included "Me." in "Me.range(sRng)"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

'If (Target.Row > 3 And Target.Row < 155) Then Cells(Target.Row, "AT") = Now()

Const sRng As String = "A5:AQ155" ' change as required
Dim sOld As String
Dim sNew As String
Dim sCmt As String
Dim iLen As Long
Dim bHasComment As Boolean


With Target(1)
If Intersect(.Cells, Me.Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
End If
sNew = .Text
sOld = .Text
.Value = sNew
Application.EnableEvents = True


sCmt = "Edit: " & Format$(Now, "dd Mmm YYYY hh:nn:ss") & " by " & Application.UserName & Chr(10) & "Previous Text :- " & sOld


If Target(1).Comment Is Nothing Then
.AddComment
Else
iLen = Len(.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
End If


With .Comment.Shape.TextFrame
.AutoSize = True
.Characters(Start:=iLen + 1).Insert IIf(iLen, vbLf, "") & sCmt
End With
End With
End Sub

Sub Hide_Comments_in_Workbook_Completely()
'This macro hides the comments and comment indicators - users wont know there is a comment within the excel workbook

Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlNoIndicator

End Sub
```