# Excel automatically add comment with cell edit history to multiple cells simultaneously

Tags: excel, vb.net

I need to add comments to cells as they are changed in Excel.  I found this thread on this site and it helped me greatly.

[Excel automatically add comment with cell edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275062/excel-automatically-add-comment-with-cell-edit-history)

I modified the code to make it a little more concise, but also comment more like we currently manually comment.

However, regardless of the changes I have made, the modified code and the original code hang up if one modifies multiple cells simultaneously, or deletes multiple cells simultaneously.

Here is my modified code.

````
Const sRng As String = "A5:AQ155" ' change as required
Dim sOld As String
Dim sNew As String
Dim sNew2 As String
Dim sCmt As String
Dim iLen As Long

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target

        sNew = .Value2
        Application.Undo
        sOld = .Value2
        .Value2 = sNew
        
        If sNew = "d" Then
        sNew2 = "Declined"
        ElseIf sNew = "D" Then
        sNew2 = "Declined"
        ElseIf sNew = "a" Then
        sNew2 = "Accepted"
        ElseIf sNew = "A" Then
        sNew2 = "Accepted"
        ElseIf sNew = "f" Then
        sNew2 = "Forced"
        ElseIf sNew = "F" Then
        sNew2 = "Forced"
        Else: sNew2 = sNew
        End If


        Application.EnableEvents = True

        sCmt = sNew2 & ": " & Format$(Now, "mm/dd/yy") & " by " & Application.UserName & Chr(10) '& "Previous Text :- " & sNew2


        If .Comment Is Nothing Then
            .AddComment
        Else
            iLen = Len(.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
        End If

        With .Comment.Shape.TextFrame
            .AutoSize = True
            .Characters(Start:=iLen + 1).Insert IIf(iLen, vbLf, "") & sCmt
        End With

    End With

End If

End Sub```

I know there are other things I can clean up with the code, regarding the nested if then statements.  That is a project for another day.  What I need help with is the error on multiple deletes or multiple pastes. 

Thanks!
````

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop to look at each cell in the intersection individually.

```
...

Dim rng as Range

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each rng in Intersect(Target, Me.Range(sRng))
       With rng 
       ...
       End With
    Next rng
End If

...
```

Comment: Everytime I try to use this, I get a next without for compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have modified the code, and incorporated the suggestion from Axuary.  But I was still have the same problem.  If I try to delete the contents of multiple cells at once, I got and error.  "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"  In the debug it.

It would always fault at the changing of the value to uppercase.  So I moved that code around a few times until I got it to work.

Now it can automatically insert and append the comments.  And, I can deleted multiple cells at the same time.

Thanx Axuary.

Here is the final code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

'If (Target.Row > 3 And Target.Row < 155) Then Cells(Target.Row, "AT") = Now()

Const sRng As String = "A1:AQ155" ' change as required
Dim sOld As String
Dim sNew As String
Dim sCmt As String
Dim iLen As Long
Dim bHasComment As Boolean


With Target(1)
If Intersect(.Cells, Me.Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
End If
sNew = .Text
sOld = .Text
.Value = sNew




        If sNew = "d" Then
        sNew2 = "Declined"
        Target.Value = VBA.UCase(Target.Value)
        ElseIf sNew = "D" Then
        sNew2 = "Declined"
        ElseIf sNew = "a" Then
        sNew2 = "Accepted"
        Target.Value = VBA.UCase(Target.Value)
        ElseIf sNew = "A" Then
        sNew2 = "Accepted"
        ElseIf sNew = "f" Then
        sNew2 = "Forced"
        Target.Value = VBA.UCase(Target.Value)
        ElseIf sNew = "F" Then
        sNew2 = "Forced"
        Else: sNew2 = sNew
        End If

Application.EnableEvents = True


sCmt = Application.UserName & Chr(10) & sNew2 & " on " & Format$(Now, "mm/dd/yy")    '& "Previous Text :- " & sNew2


If Target(1).Comment Is Nothing Then
.AddComment
Else
iLen = Len(.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
End If


With .Comment.Shape.TextFrame
.AutoSize = True
.Characters(Start:=iLen + 1).Insert IIf(iLen, vbLf, "") & sCmt
End With
End With
End Sub
```