# Automatically add comment with cell edit history having no character limit

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275062/excel-automatically-add-comment-with-cell-edit-history)

Need help

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

'If (Target.Row > 3 And Target.Row < 155) Then Cells(Target.Row, "AT") = Now()

Const sRng As String = "A5:AQ155" ' change as required
Dim sOld As String
Dim sNew As String
Dim sCmt As String
Dim iLen As Long
Dim bHasComment As Boolean


With Target(1)
If Intersect(.Cells, Me.Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
End If
sNew = .Text
sOld = .Text
.Value = sNew
Application.EnableEvents = True

sCmt = "Edit: " & Format$(Now, "dd Mmm YYYY hh:nn:ss") & " by " & Application.UserName & Chr(10) & "Previous Text :- " & sOld

If Target(1).Comment Is Nothing Then
.AddComment
Else
iLen = Len(.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
End If

With .Comment.Shape.TextFrame
.AutoSize = True
.Characters(Start:=iLen + 1).Insert IIf(iLen, vbLf, "") & sCmt
End With
End With
End Sub

Sub Hide_Comments_in_Workbook_Completely()
'This macro hides the comments and comment indicators - users wont know there is a comment within the excel workbook

Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlNoIndicator

End Sub
```

The above code works fine only one problem I am facing.
It creates a history of 9 changes in 9 lines in comments if the changes exceeded or Total Character (with space) in comments is 268 more then the previous line is automatically erased.

Can anyone help me to overcome the above problem?

I want no bindings of changes or character input or line limits.

Thanks in advance and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

`Characters` is limited in the length of text you can address.  You could instead delete and re-add the comment with the new text added.

This worked for me in testing:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const sRng As String = "A5:AQ155" ' change as required: must be a contiguous range
    
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range, oldVals, newVals, newValsTgt, usr
    Dim col As Long, rw As Long, txt As String, s As String
    
    If Target.Areas.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'only handling single Area changes
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(sRng))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error GoTo haveError
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'don't re-trigger event
    newValsTgt = ToArray(Target)     'get current Target values
    newVals = ToArray(rng)           'get current values for range of interest
    Application.Undo                 'restore previous values
    oldVals = ToArray(rng)           'get pre-update values for range of interest
    Target.Value = newValsTgt        'restore the Target range values
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    usr = Application.UserName
    
    For rw = 1 To UBound(newVals, 1)                     'loop over the new values
        For col = 1 To UBound(newVals, 2)
            If newVals(rw, col) <> oldVals(rw, col) Then 'was the content changed?
                Set c = rng.Cells(rw, col)
                s = "Edit: " & Format$(Now, "dd Mmm YYYY hh:nn:ss") & _
                    " by " & usr & Chr(10) & _
                    "Previous Text :- " & oldVals(rw, col)
                If c.Comment Is Nothing Then
                    c.AddComment s
                Else
                    txt = c.Comment.Text
                    c.Comment.Delete
                    c.AddComment s & vbLf & txt
                End If
                c.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
            End If
        Next col
    Next rw

    Exit Sub 'normal exit
haveError:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'ensure events are back on
End Sub

'returns the value of both single cells and ranges as an array...
Function ToArray(rng As Range)
    Dim rv
    If rng.CountLarge = 1 Then
        ReDim rv(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        rv(1, 1) = rng.Value
        ToArray = rv
    Else
        ToArray = rng.Value
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Added working example above.

Comment: It works as expected in other worksheets but not in my actual worksheet. Don't know what to do.

Comment: Can't know what to do? will someone help in this regard, Highly Appreciate the help in this regard.

Comment: What does it do instead of work?  Does the event fire when you can a cell?  I can't see your file...

Comment: I check the code and find that If I write anything in the SRng "A5:AQ155" then the comments are created but if text input in that cell generates automatically then comments are not added. Can you check on that issue? Thanks, Tim Williams for your kind help.

Comment: If you have cells with formulas then any changes in those cells will not trigger the change event.

Comment: No, I don't have formula in that cells. If I select an option from the text box in another cell then the specific text is imputed (using Worksheet_Change). Auto text input vba. Hope it will trigger the change event.

Comment: "the specific text is imputed (using Worksheet_Change). Auto text input vba."  I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Hi, Tim Williams, My data range is L9:M100, In L9:L100 there is a list box form. Suppose In L9 When I select any data in that list box. then the selected data unload in L9 and the assigned text for the selected data unload in the M9 cell. If L9 data changes then again the selected text unloads and the assigned text automatically unloads in M9. These changes are recorded in the comments box. Excuse me for my English. Hope you understand.

Comment: "Suppose In L9 When I select any data in that list box. then the selected data unload in L9 and the assigned text for the selected data unload in the M9 cell" exactly how does that happen though?

Comment: Here I am giving an example of how the data goes to M9 `Dim sM As String
    For Each Cell In Target
    If Cell.Column = Range("L9:L100").Column Then
        If Cell.Value = "To Paid" Then
    sM = InputBox("Input Date As DD/MM/YYYY", "Paid on", Default:=Date)
    Cells(Cell.Row, "Q").Value = CDate(sM)
    If Cell.Value = "To Paid" Then Cells(Cell.Row, "M").Value = "Bill Paid on " & Cells(Cell.Row, "Q").Value
    End If` There is lot more. And in L9:L100 I am Using a List Box Form for data entry.

Comment: OK I've no idea and it's getting way out of range of your original question, which I think I've answered as much as I can.  If you have a specific problem getting it all to work together then you might consider hiring someone for that.

Comment: Sorry to hear. I am really unable to describe it clearly. So If I type data then data records in comments but if I use user form for data entry then it will not trigger the change event. Just tell me how to overcome this issue, In my first code, it worked but only stored a specific number of words or lines.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the first time you even mentioned a UserForm...

Comment: Sorry, for my less understanding & poor description. Hope you will help me Tim Williams.

Comment: If you can share the workbook I can maybe take a look.  I can't offer much without that.  If you drop your email here I will send you a mail (then you can remove it)

Comment: Sent you a mail - you can remove your email address...